# Using form action with onsubmit doesn't work (PHP + JS)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Website works like that there is a radio button with satisfaction from a product.
There are 2 options (sts1 and sts2) and if client selects any of those 2 they get to satisfied page after sending a form to an email.
3 other options (dsts1, dsts2, dsts3) get client to dissatisfied page after sending a form to an email.

The problem is that: when i press submit button it takes me to satisfied or dissatisfied page based on the radio button but I don't get any email from that form. I've commented out onsubmit="return redirection();" and It worked normally and I got an email but I need that redirection as well. Im kind of new so I would appreciate a little help with that.

HTML

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="msform" method="POST" action="send.php" name="frm" onsubmit="return redirection();">
```

JS

```
function redirection() {
if(document.getElementById('sts1').checked || document.getElementById('sts2').checked){
        window.location='satisfied.html';
        return false;
    }
if(document.getElementById('dsts1').checked || document.getElementById('dsts2').checked || document.getElementById('dsts3').checked){
        window.location='dissatisfied.html';
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: You're never posting this info to your php... you're intercepting the submit and redirecting the user. Redirecting should happen in your PHP, not in your JS

Comment: You've got 2 options here. You can either remove the `onsubmit` handler entirely and have everything done by your PHP backend - including the redirect. Alternatively (and a little more complex, for no particular benefit imo), you could have a submit handler which sends the request via Ajax (to ensure the email is sent) and redirects on the client-side.

Comment: There's really no need to involve JS into this. This needs to be a regular form submission with all the logic done in the backend.